# Manually schedule backup in of Postgresql within Azure?

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a PostgreSQL database on Azure and it is currently automatically backed up frequently and its backups last for 7 days Basic Tier. Can I manually schedule a (daily/weekly) backup, but in a way that the database remains on Azure (e.g. Blob storage) for more than 7 days?

Searching on Azure documentation, I found something on Functions, but I tried to create a "Timer" function and couldn't figure out if it's possible to do what I want and there was no option for Python which I prefer. Ideally it would let me import crontab and schedule a pg_dump in an Azure storage. My other option I guess is to use crontab from a dedicated server where I dump the database and then move it back to an Azure blob.

Comment: I have talked with the product manager for "Azure Functions for Python", and they told me that the new version of AF for Python will come in approx. 1 month or so. And the new version will be a total rework and work with all trigger types. Hope this info helps.

Comment: It helps a bit yes. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Have you thought about just hooking up the blob storage as a mounted disk on the VM?